'hidden' applies the same CSS properties as 'flex'
I have a logo on my website, and I used hidden to hide the logo until the screen reaches a certain size. I am getting the error the "flex" and "hidden " does the same thing, but if I remove either "flex" or "hidden" then my code will not function as intended. The error does not affect my code but I was wondering why it was happening and if I could resolve it. I am using Next.js and Tailwind CSS.
className="w-16 h-16 bg-dark text-light flex items-center justify-
center rounded-full text-2xl font-bold border 
border-solid border-transparent dark:border-light hidden lg:flex"


This is happening because you are applying flex and hidden classes on the same breakpoint. Tailwind is mobile-first, so these classes that handle element display are being applied simultaneously on the mobile breakpoint. If you want to get rid of the error and the logo to only show up until your screen gets to a certain breakpoint, then you can refactor your className attribute as follows:
className="hidden w-16 h-16 bg-dark text-light items-center justify-
center rounded-full text-2xl font-bold border 
border-solid border-transparent dark:border-light lg:flex"

